# Problem with journal not appearing in reference (using chicago style)

Tags: bibtex

I am using the `natbib` package and the `\bibliographystyle{chicago}` for my references.

They are showing up in my References section, however the full citations in this section are omitting the journals.

Can someone help me understand why, or how to fix?

Here's my minimal example:

---

.tex file

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage, setspace, graphicx, rotating, nth, amsmath, booktabs, multirow, appendix, natbib, caption, lscape, mathtools,verbatim}
\graphicspath{{./Images/}}
\hyphenpenalty=3000


\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \end{titlepage}

    \newpage
    \singlespacing

    \bibliographystyle{chicago}
    \bibliography{biblio16-17.0213}

    \newpage

\end{document}
```

---

Here's the bibtex code I see:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {0.1}Description of interventions}{1}}
\bibstyle{chicago}
\bibdata{biblio16-17.0213}
\bibcite{bruhn_mckenzie}{{1}{Bruhn and {McKenzie}}{{Bruhn and {McKenzie}}}{{}}}
\bibcite{nber2018}{{2}{Corcoran et~al.}{{Corcoran, Jennings, Cohodes, and Sattin-Bajaj}}{{}}}
\bibcite{king_2007}{{3}{King et~al.}{{King, Gakidou, Ravishankar, Moore, Lakin, Vargas, Téllez-Rojo, Ávila, Ávila, and Llamas}}{{}}}
```

---

Here's the `biblio16-17.0213.bib` file where the citation is found

```
@article{bruhn_mckenzie,
    title = {In Pursuit of Balance: Randomization in Practice in Development Field Experiments},
    volume = {1},
    issn = {1945-7782},
    url = {https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/app.1.4.200},
    doi = {10.1257/app.1.4.200},
    shorttitle = {In Pursuit of Balance},
    abstract = {We present new evidence on the randomization methods used in existing
experiments, and new simulations comparing these methods.
We
find that many papers do not describe the randomization in detail. ({JEL} C83, C93, O12)},
    pages = {200--232},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {American Economic Journal: Applied Economics},
    author = {Bruhn, Miriam and {McKenzie}, David},
    urldate = {2018-05-31},
    date = {2009-10},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Snapshot:/Users/andreamcornejo/Zotero/storage/RK7KP6U8/articles.html:text/html}
```

Comment: You `bib` file looks like it is in the format `biblatex` expects, not `bibtex`. `bibtex` uses the `journal` field, not `journaltitle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `bib` file is set up for `biblatex`, not `bibtex` with `natbib`. So most of the fields you have are not supported and some need to be substituted (`date`→`year` and `month` and `journaltitle`→`journal`).

You want your entry to look something like in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bruhn_mckenzie,
    title = {In Pursuit of Balance: Randomization in Practice in Development Field Experiments},
    volume = {1},
    pages = {200-232},
    number = {4},
    journal = {American Economic Journal: Applied Economics},
    author = {Bruhn, Miriam and {McKenzie}, David},
    year = {2009},
    month = oct,
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Alternatively, you could use `biblatex` which gives more flexibility and supports all the fields in your `bib` entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bruhn_mckenzie,
    title = {In Pursuit of Balance: Randomization in Practice in Development Field Experiments},
    volume = {1},
    issn = {1945-7782},
    url = {https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/app.1.4.200},
    doi = {10.1257/app.1.4.200},
    shorttitle = {In Pursuit of Balance},
    abstract = {We present new evidence on the randomization methods used in existing experiments, and new simulations comparing these methods. We find that many papers do not describe the randomization in detail. ({JEL} C83, C93, O12)},
    pages = {200-232},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {American Economic Journal: Applied Economics},
    author = {Bruhn, Miriam and {McKenzie}, David},
    urldate = {2018-05-31},
    date = {2009-10},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Snapshot:/Users/andreamcornejo/Zotero/storage/RK7KP6U8/articles.html:text/html}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[authordate,natbib]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: @andreamcornejo If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark left of it.